# Bisection Method: Not enough inputs error

Tags: matlab

I've written the following code for Bisection Method:

```
f1=input('Enter the equation:','s');
f=inline(f1);
e1=input('Enter the first end:');
e2=input('Enter the first end:');
acc=input('Enter the accuracy:');
disp('*******************************');
m=(e1+e2)/2;
i=0;
while abs(f(m))>acc
    i=i+1;
    fprintf('%d)\t%f\tf(x)=%f\n',i,m,f(m));
    if (f(m)*f(e2))<0
        e1=m;
    else
        e2=m;
    end
    m=(e1+e2)/2;
end 
fprintf('%d)\t%f\tf(x)=%f\n',i,m,f(m));
disp ('************************');
fprintf('The root of equation by bisection method (Accuracy Type) = %f\n',m);
```

This works for some simple equations (Ex; `x^2-6`) but it does not work for complex equations like:  `e-x(3.2 sin(x) - 0.5 cos(x))` on the interval `[3, 4]`.
I am getting the following error:

[image: Error message]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of the error is that you've missed some multiplication signs (`*`) and `e` is not any built-in variable.

You're inputting `e-x(3.2 sin(x) - 0.5 cos(x))` incorrectly. It is meant to be inputted like this:

```
exp(1) - x*(3.2*sin(x) - 0.5*cos(x))
```

Other than that, in the 4th line of your code, you might mean to write this instead:
 `e2=input('Enter the last end:');` i.e. ***`last`*** instead of ***`first`***